# Why is my class considered abstract?

Tags: c++, qt, virtual-functions, abstraction

I want to implement an abstract class, but can't override purely virtual functions. For this reason compiler thinks of my class AddDialog_av as an abstract one.

It seems that compiler doesn't see the definitions in AddDialog_av.cpp file.

AddDialog.h (supposed to be an abstract class):

```
class AddDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AddDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~AddDialog();

protected:
    virtual QString generateId()=0;
    virtual bool validate()=0;

private slots:
    void addButton_clicked();
    void cancelButton_clicked();

};
```

AddDialog_av.h (supposed to be instantiated):

```
#include <adddialog.h>

class AddDialog_av : public AddDialog
{
public:
    AddDialog_av();

};
```

AddDialog_av.cpp:

```
#include <adddialog_av.h>

bool AddDialog_av::validate()
{
    return true;
}

QString AddDialog_av::generateId()
{
    return "Fork out of here.";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "adddialog_av.cpp"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    AddDialog_av w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

List of errors:

```
adddialog_av.cpp:3: error: no 'bool AddDialog_av::validate()' member function declared in class 'AddDialog_av'
    bool AddDialog_av::validate()
                                 ^
adddialog_av.cpp:8: error: no 'QString AddDialog_av::generateId()' member function declared in class 'AddDialog_av'
         QString AddDialog_av::generateId()
                                          ^
main.cpp:7: error: cannot declare variable 'w' to be of abstract type 'AddDialog_av'
         AddDialog_av w;
                      ^
```

Comment: The error message it quite clear; you should declare these member functions in the class definition of `AddDialog_av`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must tell the compiler of the override in the *declaration* of your `AddDialog_av` class. Providing an implementation the way you tried to do, i.e. specifying it in the CPP file alone, would not work, because the compiler does not even know that your `AddDialog_av` class has `AddDialog_av::generateId()` and `AddDialog_av::validate` functions in the first place. The fact that `AddDialog_av` inherits them from a base class `AddDialog` does not mean that you plan to provide an implementation in the derived class.

You must add the function to the header file as well:

```
class AddDialog_av : public AddDialog
{
public:
    AddDialog_av();
protected:
    virtual QString generateId();
    virtual bool validate();
};
```

Comment: ok. but `virtual` is not strictly needed in derived .h, not sure if all compilers like it?

Comment: I’d suggest ``override`` instead of ``virtual``. That’ll prevent typos / changes in the signature of the base class’ methods to go unnoticed.

Comment: @JonasWielicki, the base (Abstract) class declaration are _pure virtual_ methods, hence _I think_ `override` is optional. my point is that the `virtual` in _derived_ class just declares a _new_ non-pure virtual in derived class ..

Answer (score 0):

If you have =0 you must derived and implement base class AddDialog. So add

```
class MyAddDialog : public AddDialog
{
protected:
    QString generateId(){
qDebug() << "works :)";
};
    virtual bool validate(){
qDebug() << "works to :) :)";

};

};
```

and use:

```
MyAddDialog myAddDialog;
```

in code. Then it will run. Do not declare

```
AddDialog addDialog; // it will not works!!!!
```